# C++ DLL in VB crashing issue

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I have a dll that someone made me in C++.  I needed to use this dll in VB, in order to do that I had to make another dll in C++ that has functions I can call in VB.

The C++ dll I made has 4 functions.  2 callback functions that retrieve information from the original C++.  And 2 functions that I can call from VB to send that information.

I know the original dll works fine as Ive tested it endlessly in a console app.

However when I use it with my dll and VB.. I get random crashes.

There is almost no code in my VB app as its just for testing.  It just outputs the information so theres no problem there.

I believe the problem is in the C++ dll I made.  I am pretty new with C++.
I think maybe a variable gets accessed in 2spots at the same time (is this possible?) and causes it to crash?

Heres the basic layout of my C++ dll

```
//global variables
CString allInfo="";
char* info=new char[25000];

//call back function 1
HANDLE OnInfo(SendInfo* tempInfo)
{
    CString stringTemp="";
    stringTemp=tempInfo->infomessage;
    allInfo=allInfo+ stringTemp+"\n";
    return 0;
}

//function for vb
BSTR _stdcall vbInfo()
{
    allInfo=allInfo.Right(20000); //get last 20,000 characters
    strcpy_s(info,20000,allInfo);
    BSTR Message;
    Message = SysAllocStringByteLen (info, lstrlen(info));
    return Message;
}
```

Crash seems to happen completely randomly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Post the vb.net declarations for these functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from learning that Googling for the CString class reference returns some *ahem* interesting results, your problem is probably going to be the multiple access of CString.

You didn't post a lot of info, so I'm going to assume the `OnInfo` method is a callback function that is called by a thread of execution different from the one that calls `vbInfo`.  In this case, you want to look at the `CString::operator=()` method description on MSDN:

> The CString assignment (=) operator reinitializes an existing CString
>   object with new data. If the destination string (that is, the left
>   side) is already large enough to store the new data, no new memory
>   allocation is performed. You should be aware that memory exceptions
>   may occur whenever you use the assignment operator because **new storage
>   is often allocated to hold the resulting CString object.**

Given that there does not appear to be a limit on the size of what you put into the CString, it may be deallocating and allocating the memory in `allInfo` in one function while you're reading or writing it in another functions.  Things don't go so well when you suddenly try to write to unallocated memory.

You might want to look at something like a [Critical Section or a mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to keep both of your functions from hosing the common memory buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if your dll is compiled to use Unicode or ANSI strings.  You didn't say if the dll that the other person supplied to you is compiled to use Unicode or ANSI strings.  The VB caller probably gives you Unicode strings, but it is possible to make the VB caller give you ANSI strings.  So we see your code with CString of unknown type, char* pointing to an ANSI string, BSTR pointing to a Unicode string but size allocated in bytes, and who knows what.

There are a lot of articles explaining how to use Unicode, but they'd be a bit too heavy for someone who is pretty new to C++.

It would really be best if you go back to the person who made the other dll for you, and ask that person to add features that you need.  Also mention to them that you'll be calling the dll from VB, so you need their dll to handle Unicode strings.